# Проблема с addClass и removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть такой код

```
$('#'+num).addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
```

Который добавляет .active и патом удаляет предыдущее если я добавляю `.next();` то не работает

```
$('#'+num).addClass('active').prev().next().removeClass('active');
```

Как сделать активный меню который добавляет только по id и удаляет другие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из того, что вы написали - ничего не понятно. Опишите вашу проблему конкретней: что вы пытаетесь сделать и что именно не получается?

Comment: @IvanFrolov не могу сделать активный пункт меню

Comment: а консоль какие-нибудь ошибки выдает?

Comment: @IvanFrolov нет все нормально просто не заменить класс просто добавляет добавляет

Comment: И какой именно пункт меню надо сделать активным? Скиньте хоть html сюда. Плюс ко все при каких условиях выполняется ваш код? По какому событию? Очень сложно помочь вам с проблемой, не зная как и что должно работать.

Comment: @IvanFrolov не могу объяснить уже правильно ответил спасибо вам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#'+num).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```